# JavaScript only displays browser specific CSS prefixes even when others are added

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, vendor-prefix

I'm adding CSS Rules directly to the stylesheet via Javascript:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[4].style.borderRadius="10px";
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[4].style.webkitBorderRadius="10px";
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[4].style.mozBorderRadius="10px";
```

I need to display these rules later on:

```
document.write(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[4].cssText);
```

But each browser displays only its own prefixes, for example, when I'm on Chrome, I get only:

```
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
```

When I'm on Firefox, I get only:

```
-moz-boder-radius:10px;
```

How can I display them all regardless of the browser I'm using?

**PS:** I cannot use something like `document.getElementById("foo").style.width;` to display CSS, using `styleSheets[]` and `cssRules[]` is a must.

Comment: That's why it's called a *browser-specific prefix*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, because they don't exist. The browser ignores the styles that it doesn't regocnise, so the are never added to the style sheet.